# Why does a static namespace variable accessed from inside an inline class method work?

Tags: c++, static

I saw this code recently in a header file, and was surprised that it worked:

```
namespace NS {
  static int uid = 0;
  class X {
   public:
    static int getUID() { return uid++; }
  };
}
```

If the static method `NS::X::getUID()` is called from several different C++ source files, I was surprised to find that it correctly generated a unique ID (unique across translation units).  I thought that a static variable in a namespace scope had internal linkage to the translation unit.  What's going on here?  Does the inline static method in class X have it's own translation unit, and that's why it generates a unique ID?  Or is it working for me due to a quirk in my compiler?

Does the above code rely on "safe" well-defined behavior?  If so, this is a surprisingly concise method of generating a Unique ID in an inline or template class, even if it looks a bit kludgy.  Or is it better to generate a new C++ source file for a static unique ID function like this, and move the static ID inside the class?

**Update:**

For a test case, I wrote several functions like this in different files (file1.cpp, file2.cpp, etc.):

```
#include "static_def.h" // Name of the above header file.
void func1() {
  int uid1 = NS::X::getUID();
  int uid2 = NS::X::getUID();
  std::cout << "File1, UID1: " << uid1 << ", UID2: " << uid2 << std::endl;
}
```

The suprising output (after calling these from main) was:

```
File1, UID1: 0, UID2: 1
File2, UID1: 2, UID2: 3
```

Comment: Does it generate unique IDs across all translation units? Rather than each translation unit starting at 0.

Comment: Was the declaration `uid` in a header file ? Or was `uid` defined in a source file ?

Comment: Who says the function is inlined?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, UID was in a header file, I edited to clarify.

Comment: @sftrabbit: I wrote a test case with file1.cpp and file2.cpp both calling NS::X::getUID(), and each printed program-wide unique IDs (unique across translation units).  I was like...WHAT?

Comment: At this point... could you provide us with the name and version of your compiler ? Because... it just seems weird.

Comment: @BoPersson Well, of course inline is always request to the compiler, not a command.  But it is an implicit inline request declaration.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I compiled my test with gcc version 4.5.0.  The production code where I saw similar behavior was icpc version 12.1.5.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your code is only correct if you only ever include this header in a single source file.

Because `uid` is declared as `static`, it has internal linkage.  There is one instance of the `uid` variable per source file in which this header is included.  If you include this header in three source files, there will be three `uid` variables.

The `getUid` function is implicitly `inline` because it is defined inside of the class definition.  The fact that it is a `static` member function is irrelevant.  The rule for `inline` functions is that an `inline` function must be defined in every source file in which it is used, and that all of the definitions must be identical.

Your `getUid` function definition violates this rule:  yes, it is defined in every source file that includes the header (because it is defined in the header), but each definition *is different*, because in each definition the `uid` referred to is a different `uid` variable.

Therefore, your program violates the One Definition Rule and exhibits undefined behavior.  The particular behavior you observe is likely because the compiler picks one definition of the inline function and just discards the rest, so the "global variable" that you think you are using just happens to be *one of* the `uid` variables--whichever one was referenced by the copy of `getUid` that the compiler kept.  While this is a *typical* manifestation of this form of undefined behavior, the behavior is nonetheless undefined.

You can make the `uid` variable function-local to ensure that there is exactly one instance, and to avoid violating the One Definition Rule:

```
namespace NS {
  class X {
  public:
    static int getUID() {
      static int uid = 0;
      return uid++;
    }
  };
}
```

It is guaranteed in this case that there will be exactly one instance of `uid` in the program.

Comment: Okay, that's what I was suspecting, is that this is undefined behavior.  I was looking at the production code and thinking to myself "how can this possibly work!?"  Your explanation makes sense, and I will probably update the production code with a more reliable implementation (such as what you suggest).

Comment: Ah! I had not thought about the interaction with ODR for `getUID`. Well spotted!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your compiler tricks you by **not inlining** the `getUID()` method.
The fact that `getUID()` is implicitly inline doesn't mean that'll be actually inlined — it's a mere recommendation to the compiler.

Apart from that, you got it all right: UID has internal linkage and `getUID()` could've just as well returned non-unique IDs.